# The proof of the dimension of the tangent space $T_x(X)$ of a $k$-dimensional manifold is $k$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, differential-geometry, differential-topology

I am studying Guillemin and Pollack's book *Differential Topology*, and there is a proof in the book that:
The dimension of the *Tangent space $T_x(X)$* is the dimension of manifold $X$. 
Please find the proof that I found in the book in the following link.

[Prove that the dimension of the tangent space $T_x(X)$ of a k-dimensional manifold is k](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/398395/prove-that-the-dimension-of-the-tangent-space-t-xx-of-a-k-dimensional-manifo)

Assume that $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}^N$, and it is a $k$-dimension manifold. Consider a single point $x \in X$.
We know that there is an open set $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^k$, and there is an open set $V \subseteq X$ that:
$$\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
\phi &: U \rightarrow V\\
\phi^{-1}&: V \rightarrow U
\end{cases}
\end{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq1}
$$
Moreover, $\phi$ is a diffeomorphism. Therefore, both $\phi$ and $\phi^{-1}$ are bijective and smooth. The idea in the proof is to show that the $d\phi_0:\mathbb{R}^k \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^N$ is the isomorphism we need to show the dimension of the $T_x(X)$ as a vector space is $k$. In the book, there is an expansion of $\phi^{-1}$ for this issue.
At first, I had problem why we need something like  $\phi'$. Thanks to @ Christopher A. Wong post in the mentioned link, this question is solved now. 
**Now I do  not know why this smooth expansion of $\phi^{-1}$ exists?**
I know we we can have a smooth function on an open set of $\mathbb{R}^N$ to $\mathbb{R}^k$. Even though, I do not know how we should expand it on whole $\mathbb{R}^N$.

Additionally, I think that if we use the expansion on the open set of $\mathbb{R}^N$ that contains x works as well! Am I missing something?

Thanks a lot for everyone's help!

Comment: Hint: What is your definition of smoothness of $\phi^{-1}$?

Comment: If $f:X \rightarrow Y$  ($X \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ and $Y \subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$) is smooth. Then for each $x \in X$ there is an open neighborhood $x \in V \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, and a smooth function $F:V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$. Additionaly, $F|_{V \cap X}=f$.

Comment: Now you should be able to answer your own question.

Comment: I do not get it! How should I make the domain to be the whole $\mathbb{R}^n$, and have  the same value on $X$ with $f$. I know I can do it locally, but these functions that we have for each point of $X$ may not have the same value in other parts. Are you saying we can merge these functions?

Comment: The proof is local, so the domain of the extension of $\phi^{-1}$ needs to be simply an open subset of $R^N$ which is a neighborhood of $x$ there. No need to extend to the entire $R^N$.

Comment: Yeah I think the local is enough for the proof, but in the book, there is $\phi': \mathbb{R}^N \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^k$. Moreover, it is a smooth function which is the same with $\phi^{-1}$ on the whole $X$!

Comment: There is no need to extend the map to the whole space. The extension is supposed to be $\Phi^{\prime}\colon W\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^k$. Feel free to make use of [this list of Errata](https://www.math.uga.edu/sites/default/files/inline-files/Guillemin_Pollack_errata.pdf) by Ted Shifrin.

Comment: Thanks a lot., so it is an error. I looked up and see it did not use $W$ at all. :)